# How to show that four circumcircles share a point?

Tags: geometry, circles

I would like some help on this question.

Given are two parallelograms ABCD and AECF with common diagonal AC, where E and F lie inside the parallelogram ABCD.  Show that the circumcircles of triangles AEB, BFC, CED, and DFA share a point.

I have drawn the figures with Geogebra
[image]
But I haven’t been successful in proving that the circumcircles share a point.

I have tried to solve it by using Miquel-Steiner’s quadrilateral theorem, but I do not know how to apply it to this special case.

Hope that someone might give me a hint.

Comment: https://www.mathe-wettbewerbe.de/fileadmin/Mathe-Wettbewerbe/Bundeswettbewerb_Mathematik/Dokumente/BWM_2023.1_Aufgabenblatt.pdf